# Как поставить ограничение на разрешение файлов?

Tags: wordpress

чтобы можно было загрузить к примеру только pdf файлы

if( isset( $_POST['upload_files'] ) ) {

```
    $site = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path = '/wp-content/uploads/files';
    $uploaddir = $site . $path;

    // cоздадим папку если её нет
    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0755 );

    $files  = $_FILES; // полученные файлы
    $done_files = array();

    // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        $file_name = $file['name'];
        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) ){
            $done_files[] = realpath( "$uploaddir/$file_name" );
            $text .= "Ссылка на файл: ".realpath( "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) . "\n";
        }
    }

    $data = $done_files ? array('files' => $done_files ) : array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.');

}
```

Comment: @Ипатьев, сколько ты уже будешь мешать юзерам получать ответы?!!!! Это вопрос по ВП!

Comment: @SeVlad а что не так-то? Конкретнее можно?

Comment: Если вопрос по вп, то тоже 100% дубль. Давайте ссылку, я поменяю

Comment: @Ипатьев на бис: это вопрос по ВП! Там решается не так!

Comment: Хотя нет, теперь уже не смогу

Comment: @Ипатьев, открой вопрос и не лезь в вопросы хотя бы по ВП.

Comment: Не могу. у меня нет рейтинга в теге вордпресс :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129479/discussion-between-sevlad-and-).

Comment: Что мешает добавить проверку mime-type/extension?

Comment: как именно? не совсем понятно

Comment: Проверяйте и ограничивайте по [MIME типу файла](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.php) через значение в $file[‘type’].

Comment: @DanielProtopopov **не надо советовать, как добавлять дыры в своё приложение**

Comment: @InDevX наверное, принципиальная небезопасность такой проверки?

Answer (score 0):

Для запрета загрузки определённых типов можно [написать плагин](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) со следующим содержимым

```
function disable_upload_types( $mimes ) {

     unset( $mimes['zip'] ); //отключаемый тип файла

     return $mimes;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'disable_upload_types' );
```

Актуальный список используемых типов можно найти в документации и коде [функции `wp_get_mime_types`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_mime_types/#source).